# How do i set the x and y coordinates of a instance in GDscript

Tags: godot, gdscript

I do not know how to set the position of a instance in gd script. The instanced shows up on the corner of the screen.

Thanks :)

Comment: An instance of what? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of instance. If it's an object that has been derived from something like a Node2D, then `position.x` or `position.y` should do it. Do you have any code we can look at?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you want 2D or 3D.

A common method is as such:

1. Create the object you want to instance in its own scene.
2. Save the object as a scene (.tscn file) - for example "Scene1.tscn"
3. Call upon your instanced scene from your main scene as follows:

   - Make sure to preload the scene you plan to instance before your `ready()` function. For example if was called "Scene1", then declare :

`onready var Scene1 = preload("res://Scene1.tscn")`

- Then, later in your code when you want to call an instance of the scene, do it as such:

  `var InstancedScene = Scene1.instance()`
       `add_child(InstancedScene)`

// This simply instances the scene (I think at co-ordinates (0,0,0)), but you can tell it where to instance it using the following example:

For **3D** use:

`InstancedScene.transform.origin = Vector3(50.0, 0.0, -50.0)`

//Gives position  x=50, y=0, x=-50. 
This can also be used for rotation, just specify transform.basis and give a similar Vector3 coordinate set.

**OR** for **2D** use:

```
InstancedScene.position = Vector2(100.0, 100.0)
```

//This instances the object 100 pixels across and 100 pixels down. Sub in whatever values you need. You can also specify a rotation using `InstancedScene.rotation_degrees = 45` (To give 45 degrees for example)